# Android Studio debug never go into the AsyncTask

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I am new to use the Android Studio, and I find a problem when I debug the project.
After attach a Debugger to the process,I can debug it in most functions,it means I can press F8 step by step debug it. But it never go into the Asynctask,

Just like the code , I cannot get there,but the I can see the logs to confirm the code have executed.
Could anybody help me with it? Thanks

And my project is too big so we use the **multiDex.**
Here is My SyncTask, and I put a break point in the doInBackground();

```
private class GetMyApplyListCountTask extends
            AsyncTask<Void, Void, Query<MyApplyInfo>> {

        @Override
        protected Query<MyApplyInfo> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            if (mApp.getUser() != null) {
                if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(mApp.getUser().userid)) {
                    map.put("Uid", mApp.getUser().userid);
                }
                if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(mApp.getUser().mobilephone)) {
                    map.put("UserPhone", mApp.getUser().mobilephone);
                }
            }
            map.put("messagename", "getMyLoanAppList");
            map.put("CurrentPage", "1");
            map.put("PageSize", "20");
            try {
                return HttpApi.getNewQueryBeanAndList(map, MyApplyInfo.class,
                        "MyLoanInfoDetail", MyApplyCountInfo.class,
                        "MyApplyLoanInfo");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Post your code to help us better understand your question

Comment: Did you set breakpoints inside doInBackground?

Comment: did you start the asynctask, not just initialize ;)

Comment: asynctask have been executed, I can see that in logs, it just can't debug there

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` is not a main thread. Debugging multiple threads may be tricky. Check this answer for more information: [Debugging multiple threads in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375538/debugging-multiple-threads-in-eclipse) - (Eric Kaju's answer to be more precise)

Even though it's about Eclipse I don't think it will matter in your case

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, change break point suspend from Thread to All, but doesn't work