# Java thread debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, debugging

i just become desperate for the theme of debuging in eclipse. let me tell you:
my debugger in eclipse runs very good, stops right, values are readable... so long.
in our source we have many threads with this structure

```
    class Cl1 implements Runnable {
       run(){
           call cl2();
        }
    }

    class Cl2 implements Runnable {
       run(){
           call cl3(); and so on..
breakpoint-> stopMeHere();          
        }
    }
```

at the breakpoint the debugger don't stop. it doesnt care, what kind of properties of the breakpoint i set, the debugger runs over it.
it is very importent, to get this running.
does anybody has an idea, what i can do?
thanks in advice

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375538/debugging-multiple-threads-in-eclipse. The other thing is the reason of not stopping could be because of an execption in the call c13()

Comment: thx, but no succes, still no stopping.

Comment: Did you put your breakpoint at the first line of `run()`?

Comment: directly on the run method name line